# Multiple Oracle Database connections

Tags: oracle11g, connection-pooling

My application giving error when number of users increases, and the error is not able create a new connection to the Database as the number of active connection limit got reached.

When I see the database (Oracle), the number of active connections are many. I can go deep into the code, but there are many controller written by other folks and I am seriously not able to identify from they are creating new connections.

So I want to return the existing connection, without creating a new connection every time in a central location. Can I achieve that without going through all the existing code??

Comment: Are you getting an Oracle error?  If so, which error?  The error code (ORA-xxxxx) and the exact error number would be helpful.  I'm not sure what you mean by "the existing onnection" in your last paragraph.  If you have a connection pool then the middle tier has many connections open at any point in time.  It's not clear if you are describing a connection leak, which you'd need to fix by fixing your application code, or whether you're describing a problem with an underpowered or underconfigured server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin. Issue is many connections are getting created by middle layer code and connection limit got reached. So I wanted to use the existing connection If it is open, instead of creating a new connection every time. Am I clear?

Comment: No, it's not clear.  If you have a connection leak, for example, the problem is that as far as your middle tier is concerned, all the open database connections are being used by some piece of middle tier code and thus can't be given to another piece of code that is requesting a connection.  That's why I asked about the Oracle error code, for example.